# Convert substring numbers from nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion, substring

I know there are a lot of question on here about converting strings to integers in SQL but I have not been able to get anything to work with a value returned by substring.  I am using the substring function to return only the numbers from a string so I can compare the values but I'm getting an error.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I have tried running the below:

```
select 
   sy.ResourceID,
   sy.ResourceType,
   sy.Name0,
   sy.SMS_Unique_Identifier0,
   sy.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
   sy.Client0,
   Cast(Cast (substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,9,6)as Numeric(4,2)) as Int) as 'BiosVersion'
from v_R_system sy 
   inner join v_GS_FIRMWARE firm on firm.ResourceID = sy.ResourceId 
   inner join v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CS on cs.ResourceID = sy.ResourceId 
   inner join v_GS_PC_BIOS Bio on bio.ResourceID = sy.ResourceId 
where firm.SecureBoot0 != 1 and cs.Model0 = 'HP EliteBook 840 G3'
```

Casting as int rounds to `1`, when it should be `01.43` based on what the substring gets. When I remove the cast as int and just convert as numeric it truncates it `1.42`. When I try compare it to a value I specify I still get the error stated above.

```
select 
   sy.ResourceID,
   sy.ResourceType,
   sy.Name0,
   sy.SMS_Unique_Identifier0,
   sy.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
   sy.Client0,
   Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,9,6)as Numeric(4,2)) as 'BiosVersion'
from v_R_system sy 
   inner join v_GS_FIRMWARE firm on firm.ResourceID = sy.ResourceId 
   inner join v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CS on cs.ResourceID = sy.ResourceId 
   inner join v_GS_PC_BIOS Bio on bio.ResourceID = sy.ResourceId 
where firm.SecureBoot0 != 1 and cs.Model0 = 'HP EliteBook 840 G3' 
   and Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,9,6)as Numeric(4,2)) < 01.42
```

is this an issue with my comparison actually or an issue with the way I'm formatting?

Product:

- Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)
- Version: 2016 (v13.0.4604.0)
- Language: English (United States)
- Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: We need to see some sample data to be able to advise...

Comment: Have you tried increasing `numeric` to something like `numeric(10, 2)`?

Comment: Can you share some sample data, at least for the column bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0?

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is `try_cast()` instead of `cast()`:

```
try_Cast(try_Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0, 9, 6)as Numeric(4,2)) as Int) as BiosVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely getting a leading space through your `substring`. Try starting at 10 instead of 9. And make use of the `where` clause to limit you result set to only qualifying records

```
cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,10,6) as numeric(4,2))
```

Comment: Ya it looks like 10 is correct, didn't notice the space.  Looks like the comparison works now.  just using 
try_Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,10,6)as Numeric(4,2)) < 01.42  Still gets rounded if i try to cast to an int after casting to numeric, and only works with try_cast not cast.

Comment: @Keets Of course it rounds to 1 because you are trying to cast it as integer. Why not use the same as above in the select as well?

Comment: i did. i got it working with this...... try_Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0, 10, 5)as Numeric(4,2)) as BiosVersion .......and the select....... try_Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,10,5)as Numeric(4,2)) < 01.42 .......it obviously doesn't even need to be an integer to compare so that will work fine. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to cast, you can coerce a 'numeric context' by adding 0.

```
select ...
0+substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,9,6) as 'BiosVersion'
```

It may depend on your database flavor and version. Please specify.

It is possible that you have data where the specified substring is not numeric. In that case, try_cast will work (see other answer).

Comment: Yes some of the fields would return empty when this substring is applied but I am narrowing it down to only  results that would return the 4 digit number in the where clause before the substring unless it is could still be trying to run it.

Prod: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)
Version: 13.0.4604.0
Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

> Casting as int rounds to `1`, when it should be `01.43` based on what the substring gets. When I remove the cast as int and just convert as numeric it truncates it `1.42`.

First, the rounding problem. If you have more precision than two digits, you need to cast to a numeric type that includes **all** the possible digits, since any of those digits might turn out to be a tie-breaker for which way to round. Once you complete that cast, use the [`ROUND()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get the precision you actually need.

You also seem to care about the leading `0`, at least for the `SELECT` clause. I advise against that. Let client code worry about precise formatting for numbers and dates. But if you really need this, you want the [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. Again, use this *after* casting to numeric, but you can use it to replace `ROUND()`. The import thing is this produces a string value again, rather than a numeric value, so only use it for the `SELECT` clause when the client program or report expects string data.

Finally, there is a situation in the `WHERE` clause with some invalid casts. The problem here is _you cannot force SQL Server to run conditions in the WHERE clause in any specific order. Sql Server **will** process those filters in the order it believes is most efficient, even if some are needed sooner for logical reasons.

With that in mind, you should look at using [`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the WHERE clause. This will allow you to safely cast these substring to numeric values, even before other necessary filters are complete.

Comment: Can you explain how to use the round function in this situation? 
Round(try_Cast(try_Cast(substring(bio.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0,9,6) as Numeric(4,2))as INT),4) still returns 1 which will not evaluate correctly when I compare to 1.42 I don't think.
 I'm not concerned with the leading 0 as long it doesn't mess up the comparison, just wasn't sure if it had anything to do with the issue.

Comment: I think you didn't read very carefully about how to do the cast.